# Разработка модуля Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане!
Возник вопрос о создании в Netbeans собственного типа проекта...
Почитав Netbeans APi, токового не нашел =(
В основном описана разработка панелей инструментов
Может кто уже сталкивался с такой задачей?
Буду рад любой информации!

Comment: Что вы имели введу под фразой "cоздании в Netbeans собственного типа проекта" ?

Comment: Видели эту статью: https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html ? Там есть несколько вариантов, каждый с разбором.

Comment: О_о упустил... Спасибо Большое Вам!